# Jquery Ajax load only works with single word variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

Within my PHP file, I'm passing some variables around from an input box into a link, which loads a page via jQuery's ajax `load` function with that variable in its URL.

This whole system works perfectly, but it only works with single-word variables.  Anytime there is a space involved, my Ajax call breaks.  I'm assuming this is an encoding issue, but I have some doubts there as well.    Basically, it boils down to this line of code in my PHP file which is causing a ruckus.

Is it possible to find out if this is formatted correctly, or why this would break with multi-world queries?    The "Keyword" variable has jQuery's `trim` function applied to it.

```
echo  $("#addminimal").load("/addmnml?topic='.$_GET['keyword'].'")  ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi, can you put code for jquery.ajax you are using and what do you required with some examples? so we can make you show batter solutions.thx

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do any encoding at all. Jquery handles it for you:

Here's one way:

```
echo ' $("#addminimal").load("/addmnml", {topic: "'.$_GET['keyword'].'"}) ';
```

This works because `.load()` accepts a second parameter in an key-value-pair way, and does the encoding for you.

Or better, use php json:

```
$params = json_encode(array("topic" => $_GET['keyword']));
echo ' $("#addminimal").load("/addmnml", '.$params.') ';
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode spaces before sending to server:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'APage.aspx',
    data: 'word=' + encodeURIComponent('word with space'),
    success: function(Data, TextStatus, XHR)
    {

    },

    error: function(XHR)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to encode the value...

With PHP:

```
echo ' $("#addminimal").load("/addmnml?topic='.urlencode($_GET['keyword']).'") ';
```

or on the javascript side:

```
echo ' $("#addminimal").load("/addmnml?topic="+encodeUriComponent('.$_GET['keyword'].') ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I used encodeURIComponent as below

```
d_value = $("#dropdown1").val();
d_value = encodeURIComponent(d_value);
$("#dropdown2").load("drop.php?choice=" + d_value);
```

It was basically used to populate a 2nd drop down based on the selection of the first drop-down.